# Iterate over each row of a pandas df to apply dynamic multiple conditions to the whole df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, multiple-columns

The code iterates over each row of the DF and uses the value of the cols to filter the main DF and calculate the lenght of it with the filters applied. The values of the row (thus, the filters) change at each iteration.

The lines below work fine but they are too slow. Is there a way to optimize the code?

```
d = {'col_1': [111, 111, 111, 222, 333], 'col_2': [1, 9, 5, 1, 1]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    result = list()
for idx, row in DF.iterrows():
    result.append( len( DF[
        (DF['col_1']==row['col_1']) & (DF['col_2']<=row['col_2'])
        ]))
    
DF['COUNT'] = result
```

Comment: You can use [Pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

Comment: How? Can you show it?

Comment: provide minimal data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did it. Are you able to reply to the question now?

Comment: Question related to improving the efficiency of running code are more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.